# Amplify 1W output to 3W

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, audio, speakers

I'm trying to build an audio circuit using an WM8960 chip from Cirrus Logic based off a 2 mic Raspberry Pi board from Seeed studio. The chip outputs 1W per channel into an 8Ohm load but I'm finding the output volume to be on the low side when using 1w-8Ohm speaker.

Is there any way to amplify the 1W to increase output volume?

Can the output be fed into another amplifier? How would I go about increasing the volume?

For reference I've linked to the relevant documents below.

Datasheet for the WM8960 chip: https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/76/WM8960_v4.2-1142184.pdf

Schematic of board Seeed studio board I'm basing my design off: https://github.com/SeeedDocument/MIC_HATv1.0_for_raspberrypi/raw/master/src/ReSpeaker%202-Mics%20Pi%20HAT_SCH.pdf

Comment: You mean aside from using a larger/better/more powerful amp IC?

Comment: Looks like you are operating off of a \$5\:\text{V}\$ supply rail, then. Since you'd need at least an \$8\:\text{V}\$ rail, bridged-tied, to get what you want there's not much you can do about this. It doesn't want a \$4\:\Omega\$ speaker, either. So perhaps another chip is the way to go.

Comment: if you use a separate amp, it definitely wants its own supply.

Comment: @dmb If you want 3W at 8 Ohm, you want a *higher* voltage supply -- even bridged. Which is, by definition, going to be its own supply since it cannot use the existing one. So ... yeah.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the output can be fed to another amplifier. You need to take care of level and impedance matching, and design a two resistor attenuator to do this. Here's what you need to know:

1. The approximate signal level from the existing output at maximum ouput level (MOL - you can calculate this from the 1W and 8R numbers and verify with scope and a source if you have them available).
2. The signal input level for your new amp for MOL
3. The input impedance of your new amp.

Now you calculate the values of the two resistors in your divider such that the lower one of the two is **less than 10% of the input resistance** and the attenuation **reduces the MOL from the existing output to the maximum input** for the new amp.

This is the technically correct way of doing it - but sometimes this ends up sounding a bit quiet. This is because many cheap amps operate with a little bit of clipping going on. People don't notice and it makes them sound louder. If you want an easier way, you could probably get away with a 1k trimpot connected as a volume control between the stages, and tweak for a sensible sound level. But it is worth going through the numbers anyway, even if you end up not following them to the last dB.